# Styling Textarea with Background that Scrolls with Text?

Tags: scroll, textarea, notepad

I'm trying to create a textarea with a notepad background (like this: http://www.bookofzeus.com/articles/css-styling-textarea-give-notebook-notepad-look/) but I'm running into the same problem in that example of when the text goes to multiple lines past the height and is able to be scrolled through, the background doesn't scroll with it, so it looks bad with just the text floating over all the lines. Is there any way to get the background to move with the text as it scrolls and look like real writing on paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #fake_textarea{
        width:925px; 
        min-height:100%;
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background: url(http://www.artsinmotion.net/notebook_paper.jpg);
        padding-left:100px;
        font-family:arial;
      }

      #wrapper{
        width:1025px; 
        height:500px;
        overflow: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='wrapper'>
      <div id='fake_textarea' contenteditable></div>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks alcidesqueiroz, that did the trick! But in Firefox it seems as if the text doesn't wrap and continues on one line until hitting Enter or Return. How can I get it to wordwrap?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is a CSS-only method. Here is a way that uses jQuery.

It realigns the background y position with the scroll position.

http://jsfiddle.net/WTCUK/